# How to unzip ServletInputStream using zip4j library

Tags: zip, inputstream, unzip, zipinputstream, zip4j

I am uploading a zip file (heap dump) in a request through postman tool and retrieving file content in servlet using `request.getInputStream()` method.

[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEkuz.png)

I have an InputStream that contains zipped bits and would like to decompress that using a ZipInputStream. I did not see any way to currently do this using Zip4j. Currently, the only way to create a ZipInputStream is from a ZipFile which needs to be from a File and not an InputStream. I am looking for something that works similar to the way that java.util.zip.ZipInputStream works.

I have tried `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` but `getNextEntry()` method is returning NULL sometimes. Find my code below,

```
 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(request.getInputStream());
 ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

            while(ze!=null) {

                int len;
                while((len = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }

            out.close();
            zis.close();

            return out.toByteArray();
```

Is there any way to achieve this using the zip4j library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of zip4j (> 2.x)? zip4j > v2.x has ZipInputStream which takes any inputstream as input, just as jdk's ZipInputStream does.

Comment: @SrikanthReddyLingala, Exactly what I was looking for. Now I am using zip4j-2.2.4. Thank you!